# why there is random behaviuor for a background job?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, background-process

going through [advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html) example 3.3 running a loop in background, i found this :

```
#!/bin/bash
# background-loop.sh
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 # First loop.
do
echo -n "$i "
done & # Run this loop in background.
# Will sometimes execute after second loop.
echo # This 'echo' sometimes will not display.
for i in 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 # Second loop.
do
echo -n "$i "
done
echo # This 'echo' sometimes will not display.
# ======================================================
# The expected output from the script:
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
# Sometimes, though, you get:
# 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 bozo $
# (The second 'echo' doesn't execute. Why?)
# Occasionally also:
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
# (The first 'echo' doesn't execute. Why?)
# Very rarely something like:
# 11 12 13 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
# The foreground loop preempts the background one.
exit 0

# Nasimuddin Ansari suggests adding sleep 1
#+ after the echo -n "$i" in lines 6 and 14,
#+ for some real fun.
```

i dont get this, does anybody understands this.

Comment: It is because of the threading: You put something in the background and something in foreground. But both of them echoes to the same "out". So there may be some mix-ups in the printing. You can solve this by adding sleep 1 after echoes. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background jobs execute asynchronously. That means that you are note able to predict the order of execution just by definition. Theoretically, even with adding `sleep` you may still encounter the issue: waiting just for some seconds does not eliminate the async nature of the bg jobs, the only thing you're actually doing is just lowering the probability of such mix-up.